# Why is the catch case called although the promise is resolved?

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux, jestjs, redux-thunk

can someone help me understand why the .catch case is called although the prior promise is resolved successfully?
https://gist.github.com/defrian/fd6dd7f072754e833b60c7bd6ed45159
when the password is correct i recieve (why does it contain the “payload”: “signIn error”?)

```
    Array [
        Object {
          "type": "login_user",
        },
       Object {
         "payload": Object {
           "name": "signedUser",
         },
         "type": "login_user_success",
       },
       Object {
         "payload": "Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined",
         "type": "login_user_fail",
       },
      ]
```

when I use a wrong password I recieve (as I expect)

```
Array [
        Object {
          "type": "login_user",
        },
       Object {
         "payload": "signIn error ",
         "type": "login_user_fail",
       },
      ]
```

Comment: This is an interesting question, though I'd put the relevant codes into the question itself. The error message that you get `Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined` is very telling, could you find out where the error was thrown?

Comment: it seem to come from the login loginUserSuccess action creator. From the NavigationService call

Comment: That make sense then — it throw error after the success action was dispatched, hence you have a success user object, but the function still throws an error. So the promise was never resolved, it was rejected in both case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. It was caused by the NavigationService call.
As I am using redux-thunk I had to change it to `dispatch(() => NavigationService.navigate('Home'));`